# How to resize the list box of sections in NSIS MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

Tags: nsis

I want to change the basic style of the Install Files page of NSIS.
Currently it shows a list box of sections and i want that the width of this listbox will change automatically according to it's content.

And maybe to remove the other empty listbox as shown in the image below.
thanks.

I'm using MUI2 and there is the code:

```
page components
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW InstFilesShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3VD5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because of this use

```
page components
```

i changed to this and added the

```
**!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_NODESC**
!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
```

it works :)